# paste text from Notepad app into 16_GByte micro SD Card

Tags: micro-sd-card

My 16_GByte SD Card is formatted FAT32.  However, I have not found a way to simply copy text from a URL (How to make your RPi3 computer an Alarm Clock) and then paste this text into the SanDisk card. 
  After I try to paste this text, the only thing in the SanDisk card is 
the tiny bit of formatting.

Please help.  Thank you;  Don Irick.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do. How are you attempting to 'paste into' an SD card?

Comment: @Don Irick, you mentioned an URL above "How to make your RPi3 computer an Alarm Clock" but didn't link it. 1) What's the URL? 2) Are you trying to paste test from Notepad in Windows, or some other app in a different OS? Please click [Edit] and put the information requested in comments above as well as my questions into your Original Question to make this clear to us. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: SD cards are storage devices that require that you package the data into a logical containers. We call these files. You cannot simply paste a line of text into an SD card. You have to save (or move, or copy) the FILE that the text is in onto the card.

Answer (score 1):

In File Explorer, right click in the root of the SD Card on the right side window, and from the Context Menu which appears, choose **New** then **Text Document**.

Change the name from New Text Document to whatever you wish it named, and change the 'extension' (.suffix) to whatever you wish.

When you complete the rename, a Notepad window appears; enter what you wish into that text edit window, then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and save the file.